# UseState only shows on second click

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-state

I am updating state using React useState hook on click of a form submit button, the state is not updating until second click. Believe I need to use a useEffect but not sure how to implement with an onClick.

```
const files = [
  {
    id: 'foo'
  }
]

const [fieldName, setName] = useState({});


const onSubmit = () => {
    files.map((file) => {
      if (!fieldName[file.id]?.value) {
        setName(() => ({
          ...fieldName,
          [file.id]: {
            value: test[file.id]?.value,
            error: true
          },
        }));
      }
    });

    console.log(fieldName);
    // Output = {}
    // Expected Output = { foo: { error: true } }
    
    if (fieldName) // simply to show i need access to updated fieldName at this point

  };
```

Comment: useState is async function. Move your console outside of the function

Comment: I should of state I am trying to use the updated state within that function (do not continue if errors found)

Comment: @James save it into a variable. You can call setState on that variable and continue using the variable within the function.

Comment: @404 example bud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented a useEffect to set a hasError state

```
useEffect(() => {
    const hasErrors = Object.keys(fieldName).filter(
      (key) => fieldName[key].error
    );
    if (!hasErrors.length) {
      setFormHasError(() => true);
    }
  }, [fieldName]);
```

I could then use the following in code

```
if (formHasError) {
      return;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments; useState is an async function and thus does not garantuee you'll get the new value upon retrieving its value again. This is for performance reasons allowing batching of multiple state changes.

The easiest way to keep working with the new value within the same method is simply saving it into a variable as follows:

```
const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);

function onclick(e) {
  setClicked(true);
  if (clicked) { //this goes wrong as clicked likely isn't updated yet
    //do something
  }
}
```

```
const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);

function onclick(e) {
  const newClicked = true;
  setClicked(newClicked);
  if (newClicked) { //using the variable garantuees you'll get the value you want
    //do something
  }
}
```